Can you use regular curve objects as guide hairs for a hair system?
I am looking to create a hair system - either using the new geometry nodes style hair or a particle system, I don't mind that, but I was wondering if it's possible to use curves as guide hairs? Like I didn't comb guide hairs into place in the "place empty hair" mode, I modelled locks of hair using mesh, then converted the vertical edges into curves, and now I have a curve object that has all the shapes I would need to guide a hair system, but I'm not sure if I can use it? If so, how could I? Thanks! 

Maybe, but have you tried using the geometry nodes system from scratch yet? It’s really very easy once you know how to do it.

@TheLabCat Is there a node/node setup that will let me use these curves as guides?

I know that’s your main question, but have you used the system from scratch? It might actually be harder to try and save the work you’ve done and converted to correct format than just starting over. Also, I found the node hair system a bit confusing at first, so I think it would be helpful if you made sure you knew how to do it in the standard fashion as sort of an experiment control / baseline.

yeah i have, i'm asking specifically about this
